# mod of big integer to the power of big integer c#

Tags: c#, algorithm, module, biginteger, exponentiation

we were assigned a task at uni to write an algorithm for mod of power((b^p) mod m) of a big integer class that he wrote.
one of the test case is
body:3268740452599842251800072850
power:10728788472479767015096759639
mod:3425216029116239798519821463
is it possible?

my code works on smaller test cases but struggles on that case.

at first I got stack overflow error because I was calling the recursive function too much

I tried to make it tail recursive and I think I did i'm not sure

but now it doesn't output the answer to the big test case so I wrote a `console.writeline()`

to know how many steps its got left to finish calculating
and I got 1072878847247976701509675793 and it was moving at a rate of 1 per sec

that was the sample test cases file there is still a bigger one
what am I doing wrong here?
my code:

```
public static BigInteger ModOfP(BigInteger B, BigInteger P, BigInteger M)
        {
            int lenb = B.GetDigitsCount(), lenm = M.GetDigitsCount();
            BigInteger q = new BigInteger(new byte[lenb]);
            BigInteger r = new BigInteger(new byte[lenm]);

            var gg = new Tuple<BigInteger, BigInteger>(q, r);
            var ez = new Tuple<BigInteger, BigInteger>(q, r);


            if (P.Equals(zero))
            {

                return one;
            }
            else if (P.Equals(one))
            {

                return B;

            }
            else if (BigInteger.Is_Even(P))
            {

                ez = DivMod(P, two);
                gg = DivMod(ModOfP(B*B, ez.Item1, M), M);               
                return gg.Item2;

            }
            else
            {

                ez = DivMod(P-one, two);
                gg = DivMod(B * ModOfP(B*B, ez.Item1, M), M);
                return gg.Item2;
            }
        }

        public static int Bounce(BigInteger B, BigInteger P, BigInteger M, BigInteger T)
        {
            int lenb = B.GetDigitsCount(), lenm = M.GetDigitsCount();
            BigInteger q = new BigInteger(new byte[lenb]);
            BigInteger r = new BigInteger(new byte[lenm]);

            var gg = new Tuple<BigInteger, BigInteger>(q, r);
            Console.WriteLine("T:  " + T.Number_getter());
            if (T.Equals(zero))
            {
                return 0;
            }


            else
            {

                BigInteger.safe2 = BigInteger.safe2* ModOfP(B, P, M);               
                return Bounce(B, P, M, T - one);
            }
        }

 public static Tuple<BigInteger, BigInteger> DivMod(BigInteger A, BigInteger B)
        {
            int lena = A.GetDigitsCount(), lenb = B.GetDigitsCount();
            BigInteger q = new BigInteger(new byte[lena]);
            BigInteger r = new BigInteger(new byte[lenb]);

            if (A.CompareTo(B) == -1)
            {

                return Tuple.Create(zero, A);
            }

            var gg = new Tuple<BigInteger, BigInteger>(q, r);

            
            gg = DivMod(A, B+B);            
            gg = new Tuple<BigInteger, BigInteger>(gg.Item1 + gg.Item1,gg.Item2);
            if (gg.Item2.CompareTo(B) == -1)
            {

                return gg;
            }
            else
            {
                return Tuple.Create(gg.Item1 + one, gg.Item2 - B);
            }
        }

        

        //====================
        //Your Code is Here:
        //===================
        /// <summary>
        /// TODO: Write an efficient algorithm that calculates Mod of Power
        /// The function should calculates the result of the equation (B ^ P) mod M
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="B">the base, non-negative BigInteger</param>
        /// <param name="P">the exponent, non-negative BigInteger</param>
        /// <param name="M">the modulus value, positive BigInteger</param>
        /// <returns>BigInteger, The result of (B ^ P) mod M</returns>
        public static BigInteger ModOfPower(BigInteger B, BigInteger P, BigInteger M)
        {
            int lenb = B.GetDigitsCount(), lenm = M.GetDigitsCount();
            BigInteger q = new BigInteger(new byte[lenb]);
            BigInteger r = new BigInteger(new byte[lenm]);
            BigInteger.safe2 = new BigInteger(new byte[] { 1 });

            var gg = new Tuple<BigInteger, BigInteger>(q, r);
            gg = DivMod(P, BigInteger.limit);
            Console.WriteLine("gg 0: " + gg.Item1.Number_getter());
            Console.WriteLine("gg: " + gg.Item2.Number_getter());
            if (B.Equals(zero))
            {
                return zero;
            }


            Bounce(B,BigInteger.limit,M,gg.Item1);
            gg =DivMod(BigInteger.safe2* ModOfP(B, gg.Item2, M),M);

            return gg.Item2;
        }
```

Comment: I'll not give an answer since this is clearly a homework question. But as a tip I advise you to look into mathematical tricks you can use to simplify the calculation. There are 2 rules in particular (one for modulo calculation and one for power calculation) that combine into a quick algorithm for `(b ^ p) % m)` that greatly reduces the amount of calculations needed (made a quick implementation and tested this locally and was able to calculate the remainder of your provided input in 6 ms).

Comment: As a further hint along the lines of @Knoop, consider how to compute (b ^ 65536) mod m. You can multiply b by itself 65536 times, but if you're clever you can find a way to do it with only 16 multiplies.